# How to pick a good mango at a local store?

Tags: fruit, mango

Simply just like the title says. I LOVE mango. But the thing is I don't know how to pick a good one at the local store. I read some tips somewhere from Googling (long time ago, I don't remember its exact url) said to smell it, but I'm not sure what smell should the good mango have? My family and I often must wait for our mangoes in the fridge for more than 5 days just to make sure that they're ready to serve.

Advice? Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I look for a few things...

1. Colour: There are many different varieties of mangos. Some go from green to red, some end up Orange, some start off yellow and end up orange. So once you're familiar with the type of mango you're buying, you can get an idea of what a ripe one looks like.
2. Smell: A ripe mango will smell sweet. Check near the stem end, the smell should be stronger there. You should smell it and think "mango". Smell is a large part of your taste, so it should be very familiar.
3. Firmness: Mangos, like peaches will soften as they ripen. Just as it starts to go from firm to soft, it is just about ripe.
4. Weight: With most fruit you can tell their ripeness by their weight. A riper fruit will be slightly heavier than an unripe one.

As an aside, if you're at a grocery store, and you see a few different types of mangos, look for these Ataulfo mangos: http://goo.gl/IeEZ4. They're my personal favourite. The flavour is richer, and they are a lot less stringy.

Finally, DO NOT refrigerate if you want them to ripen.

[More info on the Ataulfo mangos.](http://www.produceoasis.com/Items_folder/Fruits/ataulfo-mango.asp) (There is also some generic mango info there)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the well-written answer. I'm studying both links right now.

Comment: +1 for smell. For almost any fruit and vegetable, if it doesn't smell good, it doesn't taste good either.

Comment: "A riper fruit will be slightly heavier than an unripe one." ... really? Maybe if it were ripened on the tree, but when it ripens off the tree, how does it gain weight? There isn't anywhere for the extra mass to come from.

Comment: Well, as with most mass harvested fruit, they don't exactly check each mango before picking. :-) of course you are correct, but if I'm at the store and I have a choice, I'll grab the heavier one. It won't get heavier over time in the store. The original question was just about selection.

Answer (score 5):

In the fridge?  Keep the mangos out of the fridge and they'll ripen faster, and taste better.  The smell should remind you of a delicious mango. :) (No other way to describe it, really)

Comment: oic, I've been worried and I thought it will be rotten if I keep it out of the fridge. I'll try to remember the smell of a delicious one when I eat it next time so that I know how to pick a good one. Sorry for my super duper basic question :) Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Mangos are tricky to pick ripe from the supermarket.  Not knowing, I used to assume firm was the way to go, but it was often not ripe enough.  So I picked only mangos which were soft, though those are often too ripe or bruised.

I determined that the best mangos are those that are neither too firm nor too soft.  Of course that's a largely subjective answer, but I suppose that means that it comes with experience.  Though in the case of doubt, better that they are more firm than soft, since you can always let it sit to ripen on its own.

Comment: @talon8, the yellow box said "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" to me after I upvoted all useful answers here. I can only "accept" so far.

Comment: @Arie: Ahh right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As i experienced while choosing mangoes,it have many varieties in it and their type. but still you can choose on the basis of color,firmness,smell,peel texture
,weight. The India is the top producers of mango of vivid varieties. 
before this you must know that which one you want to purchase(that is available in your region or not).
 mostly famous ones are
 http://www.india-forums.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=613788
http://mumbaiboss.com/2012/03/30/your-seasonal-guide-to-mangoes/
Smell: A ripe mango will smell sweet. Smell should be very familiar to one like ripen sweet mangoes have.
Firmness: Mangoes, will soften as they are about to ripe. Just as it starts to go from firm to soft.
Weight: A riper fruit will be slightly heavier than an unripe one.

DO NOT refrigerate if you want them to ripen with its natural sweetness,as refrigeration will results in little frozen pulp and taste less delicious.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. First check the color of mango, then smell it. If it smells sweet it's good. Remember mangoes should not be too hard or too tender.